# Restrict the number of characters in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I've seen a lot of answers, but it seems that none of them has worked. 
I have a programmatically created UIAlertView with two UITextFields.
I want to restrict the number of characters :

- 12 characters in first field
- 1 character in second field

First field code:

```
alertDialog.addTextField { (nameField) in
        nameField.placeholder = "Name"
        nameField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        nameField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        }
```

And second

```
alertDialog.addTextField { (keyField) in
        keyField.placeholder = "Key"
        keyField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        keyField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

    }
```

How can I correctly restrict the number (Let's pretend that there will be no paste in these field)

Comment: Are you adding a textField delegate?

Comment: No, not at this time. I tried but failed several times. Can you help me a bit? :)

Comment: @Tj3n, yes! This worked! Thank you a lot. I haven't seen this before. Sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set textField delegates to respective class (in my case self is ViewController)

```
nameField.delegate = self
keyField.delegate = self
```

Then you can restrict characters by

```
extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        switch textField {
        case nameField:
            if ((textField.text?.length)! + (string.length - range.length)) > 12 {
                return false
            }

        case keyField:
            if ((textField.text?.length)! + (string.length - range.length)) > 1 {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event like this:

```
textField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
textField2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```

Then implement this function:

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == self.textField1 && textField.text.length > 12 { 
        // Do whaterver you want
    }
    if textField == self.textField2 && textField.text.length > 1 { 
        // Do whaterver you want
    }
}
```

Comment: is there no other way to do this?

Comment: see @Vinupriya Arivazhagan answer's